# How do you view and edit your whitelist and blacklist in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, blacklist, whitelist

I've accidentally whitelisted a spam domain in Outlook. How can I edit find and edit the whitelist? Also I would like to investigate the blacklist, but I cannot find any links to either of these in the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Outlook 2010/2013, click the **Junk** button on the ribbon and select **Junk E-Mail Options**. You'll find the whitelists on **Safe Senders** and **Safe Recipients** tabs. Blacklist is on **Blocked Senders** tab.

Comment: Thanks. That was much more straightforward than I expected.